# How to find Div id inside Static method using C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<div class="row" id="div1" runat="server">
</div>
```

My method is like this

```
 public static bool CheckEmail() {
   int result=1;
   if(1) 
   { 
     div1.Visible=true; // here am not able to get div id 
   } 
   else { 
      div1.Visible=false; // here am not able to get div id}
   }
```

Comment: Why is the method static? Is it in the code-behind of the page? Where and how do you call the CheckEmail() method.

Comment: my scenario is while entering textbox value as  email id then client call through page method am validating and returning back

Comment: @Muthu - Hey in that case your task is real simple, you can show\hide the div at client side itself, Check my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Static` method can only access static variables. And all the controls are non-static i.e they don't exist once like static methods for each instance of page but changes after each postback so you won't be able to access them. So you will have to make your method non-static or you can do it from client side as well or you can use `UpdatePanel`.

**Update:**

Since you are calling this from client side, you can return the response and show\ hide the div at client side itself:-

```
[WebMethod] 
public static bool CheckEmail(string MailId) 
{ 
    if(condition) 
        return true;
    else
        return false; 
}
```

At Client side:-

```
success: function(response){
      if(response.d == true) 
          $("#div1").hide();
      else
          $("#div1").show(); 
}
```

Comment: script manager that this method is accessible through javascript we need to ensure two things. First this method should be 'public static'. Second there should be a [WebMethod] tag .

Now I have created server side function which creates account. Now we have to call it from client side. Here is how we can call that function from client side

Comment: @Anirudh - Yeah I agree you can do that way but OP is calling this method from server side and not client side right?

Comment: yea . i mean to say that he can, but not directly in static method

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HtmlAgility](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
var divs =  document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'row')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
I don't no why are you using bool there, where you are not returning any value. If you are using void then below code will work. U can use div inside static method. For that you have to call your class. Just like this...

```
 public static void CheckEmail() {
 <classname> d = new <classname>(); // write your class name
 int result=1;
 if(result ==1) 
  {

   d.div1.Visible=true; 
  } 
  else {

   d.div1.Visible=false; 
   }
  }
```

Comment: inside static method div id am not able to get ? i dont have any class for that

Comment: did u call class name ?

Comment: For example if ur class name is class1, write, class1 n=new class1(); then call , n.div1

Comment: [WebMethod]
    public static bool CheckEmail(string MailId)
    {
        return (Convert.ToBoolean(Response.ReturnValue))
    }